# Retrofit 2 загрузка изображений с сервера

Tags: android, retrofit

Имеется класс product.
В базе данных хранится ссылка на изображение. При отображение свойств продукта в телефоне, необходимо также загрузить изображение.
Как это можно сделать с помощью Retrofit 2.

До этого загружал только свойства, с изображениями дело не имел.
Может у кого пример рабочий есть?

В качестве REST использую SLIM. Как на нем подготовить ответ

Comment: вот пример https://www.learn2crack.com/2017/08/upload-image-using-retrofit.html

Comment: @Cypher это вроде загрузка на сервер? судя по скриншотам. А мне нужно на телефон скачать

Comment: или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: перепутал..вот загрузка с сервера https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/networking/android-retrofit-2-0-tutorial-retrofit-android-example-download-image-url-display-android-device-screen/

Comment: Вот еще, https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-download-files-from-server